# Method to drop 50% packets of the total

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, bash, packet-capture

On my machine I want that only 50% packets will receive.

I am working on centOS 5.5.

For that I searched on net. I got IPtables. I used random patch of IPtables.

**Command**

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m random --average 50 -j DROP
```

**Output**

```
iptables v1.3.5: Couldn't load match `random':/lib64/iptables/libipt_random.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

But above shows that that library is missing.

Then, How can I drop 50 % packets of the total. Please correct my above method  or suggest new one.

Tell me how to add these libraries into the IPtables existing package. [I tried, but these libraries is not found on internet]

**Edit No. 1**

I further need logging for the dropped packets, so I changed my iptables ruleset as follows:

`iptables -L -n -v` output is [this is running on system 1]

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1875K packets, 114M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   23  2392 random_drops  icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           statistic mode random probability 0.500000

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 2121K packets, 206M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain random_drops (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   23  2392 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix `dropped randomly: '
   23  2392 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Then I run a script (This script is running on system 2 in two instances to create more traffic)

```
while [ 1 ]; do
    rsh a.b.c.d pwd;
done
```

on two systems. But there is no log formed.

3. /var/log/messages permission is -rw------- root:root.
4. /var/log/syslog is not present.

What am I missing?

Comment: What OS are you using, debian, ubuntu?

Comment: @NickW centOS 5.5

Comment: What happens if you use  `-m statistic --mode random` instead of `-m random`?

Comment: @NickW statistic is also missing.

Comment: You really should be looking into [`netem`](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem#Packet_loss) for simulations of network conditions.

Comment: In the meantime, try installing iptables-sources. Here's one possibility: http://pkgs.org/centos-5-rhel-5/centalt-i386/iptables-sources-1.3.5-5.el5.noarch.rpm.html

Comment: @NickW I have iptables-1.3.5-5.3.el5_4.1.x86_64.rpm
rpm for IPtables. I am working on centOS.

Comment: @syneticon-dj When I run `tc qdisc change dev eth0 root netem loss 0.1%` command it shows `RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory`

Comment: I know, which is why I recommended you install that package, it's a rhel5 rpm for obtaining the modules you want..

Comment: @NickW When I try to uninstall previous installed rpms, it fails . It said `error: Failed dependencies:
        iptables = 1.3.5 is needed by (installed) iptables-ipv6-1.3.5-5.3.el5_4.1.x86_64
        iptables is needed by (installed) iptstate-1.4-2.el5.x86_64
        iptables >= 1.2.8 is needed by (installed) system-config-securitylevel-tui-1.6.29.1-6.el5.x86_64.
`. What to do then?

Comment: Skip it and figure out how to get netem working I guess :)

Comment: @NickW But netem also showing error, show in above comments please. Help me. I need this setup.

Comment: @NickW Can I install iptables that you suggested over installed one?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8010/discussion-between-nickw-and-jhamb)

Comment: The trouble in your [Edit No. 1] section seems to be that you are logging/dropping ICMP traffic but the `rsh` executions would induce TCP traffic - so there simply is nothing that is caught by the rules (the number of "pkts" in `iptables -L -v -n` output is telling you how often this rule has matched since creation or counter reset - yours has matched 23 times which is not all that much for an endless loop). Other than that, as this is a different problem, it is best to ask a different question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CentOS 5.5 does neither have the ipt_random nor the ipt_statistic modules preinstalled. You might revert to the [CentosALT repository](http://centos.alt.ru/) (excuse my Russian) and use the readily compiled statistic module from there:

```
wget http://centos.alt.ru/repository/centos/5/x86_64/centalt-release-5-3.noarch.rpm
# [...]
rpm -Uvh centalt-release*rpm
# [...]
yum install ipt_statistic
```

and running

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.50 -j DROP
```

should yield the rule you want.

Note from the Netem documentation:

> **Caveats**
>
> When loss is used locally (not on a bridge or router), the loss is
>   reported to the upper level protocols. This may cause TCP to resend
>   and behave as if there was no loss. When testing protocol reponse to
>   loss it is best to use a netem on a  bridge  or  router

although this obviously would not apply as long as you are just DROPping in the INPUT chain.

Comment: Very well explained. Can you tell me netem installaion also. As it shows `RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
` by running command `tc qdisc change dev eth0 root netem loss 0.1%`. [I am in root right now]

Comment: When I tested the instructions that you said in the chat by putting `rsh` command in infinity on three systems, and run that scripts on all three. But there is no log formed. [ ONCE LOG IS FORMED IN THE BEGINNING, THEN I CLEAN THAT /VAR/LOG/MESSAGES BY `: > /var/log/messages`. BUT AFTER THAT NO LOG IS FORMED]. why this happens, help me please.

Comment: Check edit no. 1, that shows all my process.

Comment: I solved the problem, when I reboot, all things are going fine.

Comment: By using above command, we can drop 50% packets of all coming on machine. Am i right ? But when I run above script on systems, it gets answer, why? It should print only 5 outputs , if the while loop iterates 10 times. If I am  wrong , correct me please .

Comment: @jhamb as already noted, the given iptables rule only would affect ICMP traffic. As `rsh` is using TCP for its connections, it would be entirely unaffected. If you would exchange `-p icmp` by `-p tcp` it *would* be affected but as TCP has own algorithms to handle packet loss, you likely would not see *"just 5 successful connections out of 10"* but simply significantly slowed down connection and reaction times (resulting from timeouts and retransmissions).

Comment: What about `--icmp-type`. Is it also required to replace with `--tcp-type` ?

Comment: @jhamb no, there is no `tcp-type` option to the TCP protocol handler in iptables. If you only want it to affect rsh traffic, you should add a `--dport 514`. For other selectors, take a look at the iptables man page and examples available on the net - for example [these ones](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/06/iptables-rules-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a *kernel* configuration issue. See `iptables-extensions(8)`, it explains the `statistic` module:

```
iptables ... -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.5 ...
```

(fill in `...` as required).

This is kernel configuration `CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_STATISTIC`, set to module here (Fedora 18, kernel-3.8.3-201.fc18.x86_64, iptables-1.4.16.2-5.fc18.x86_64). There is no matching `ipt_statistic` shared object around for the `iptables` userland executable.

Comment: He would need to go through the Kernel compilation procedure which he appears unfamiliar with. It is so much easier to install a package.

Comment: What package, if a kernel with the correct configuration is needed?

Comment: you do not need to reconfigure the kernel, what you need is the module binary matching the kernel's version. Take a look at my answer - the CentOSALT repository is maintaining this very module as a package.